# C prints other integer number than what it shows on Watches. Why is that?

Tags: c

I tried adding watches and debugging it step by step,and although it works correctly on watches,it doesn't print the right value. What could be the reason for this outcome?
I'm a newbie, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,pal,nr;
    printf("Introd un numar : ");
        scanf("%d",&nr);
    n=  nr;
    pal=0;
    while(n!=0) {
        pal=pal*10+n%10;
        n=(int)n/10;
    }
    if (pal==nr)
        printf("%d este palindrom ",&pal);
    else
        printf("%d nu este palindrom ",&pal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove ampersands in `printf`

Comment: Lol.. Thanks! 
Why is that happening? The adress of the value shouldn't be the same as the value itself?

Comment: Eh? The value shouldn't be the same as the address in absolute majority of cases.

Comment: "The address of the value shouldn't be the same as the value itself?" - of course not. Suppose you have `int a = 0;` and `char b = 1;`. Where do you place them? If at addresses zero and one, then the second byte of `a` will suddenly become 1 (because `int`s are greater than 1 byte)

Comment: The address points the place, where the value is held - so there is no relation between address and value. It means, you can write value 1 at specified address, then write value 123 at the same address - the last value will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `printf` calls like below:

```
if (pal==nr)
    printf("%d este palindrom ",pal);
else
    printf("%d nu este palindrom ",pal);
```

Comment: I would add braces too - not strictly necessary. `if (pal==nr) {
    printf("%d este palindrom ",pal);
} else {
    printf("%d nu este palindrom ",pal); }`